# .ajax() Bad Request 400

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

So I built the code for a web application on WAMP (my first time using any server stuff) and a test database we made looking at the client's databases.  When trying to implement, we have run into a lot of trouble.  They are using an enterprise server (NOTE: I have no idea what I am talking about here) and MSSQL where I just used localhost, root, and no password on WAMP with MYSQL.  I have no idea how to help them get the product implemented.  It works fine on my computer but for them, it says Bad Request 400 when I have AJAX print out the error text.

ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getJobList.php",
        data: "hline="+lineLabel[currentLine],
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
              //do successful stuff
        }
}
```

php file

```
<?php

include "config.php";

$con = mysql_connect($host);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
//get the parameter from URL
$hline=$_GET["hline"];
if (empty($hline)){
    echo "1"; //default rate
}
else{
    $db=mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $pass);//connect to local database
    mysql_select_db($databaseName, $db);//select the database you want to use
    if (!$db){
        echo ("error connecting to database");              
    }
    else{
        //connection successful
        $sql = " SELECT partparameters.cspc,processingrate,setuptime,lotsize,duedate,duetime,homeline
        FROM jobs
        INNER JOIN partcoding 
        ON jobs.partnumber=partcoding.partnumber
        INNER JOIN partparameters
        ON partcoding.cspc=partparameters.cspc
        WHERE homeline = '$hline'
        ORDER BY duedate,duetime ASC";//sql string command
          $result=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());//execute SQL string command
          //result contains rows
          $arr = array();
          $num = 0;
          while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
            $array[$num] = $rows;
            $num++;
          }
          echo json_encode($array);
    }
}

?>
```

php config file

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$databaseName = "gmdata1";
?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Fixed a stray parenthesis that I mistyped when posting.  Also if it makes a difference I developed on Chrome and the Users are using Firefox.  I dont think it should make a difference though because they render the same.

EDIT 2:

> Request URL:

```
http://usmmcsa0wwt01/ProdSched/getJobList.php?hline=G%20%201
```

> Request Method:
>      GET
>
> Status Code:
>      HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
>
> Request Headers
>      15:24:24.000

```
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequestUser-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0Referer:http://usmmcsa0wwt01/ProdSched/index.phpHost:usmmcsa0wwt01Connection:keep-aliveCache-Control:max-age=0Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflateAccept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

> Response Headers
>      Δ2ms
>
> Server:CIMPLICITY-HttpSvr/1.0Date:Mon, 22 Apr 2013 19:24:24 GMT

This is what I get in their firefox console inspect HTTP request

Comment: You talk about mssql in the text, but are using mysql in the code? Two entirely different databases...

Comment: Your server is returning a Bad Request, which means the data is malformed. Please post the response. If there is no response, then posting the code above and fixing the minor errors may be futile

Comment: @MarcB We originally used an Access database and converted it to mysql..for them we converted it to mssql

Comment: @popnoodles Bad Request is literally all that the console logs.  What should I give you?

Comment: The problem isn't in the jquery. You need to open that page getJobList.php in the browser not via ajax to find the problem. If all other avenues fail `echo __LINE__` and die until you find the line that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is wrong. To pick up `$_GET["hline"]` you either want `hline="+lineLabel[currentLine]` in the URL (not recommended) or format the data correctly.

```
data: {"hline": lineLabel[currentLine]},
```

Comment: That did not fix the problem, it is still returning bad request

Answer (score 0):

Try this  -

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getJobList.php",
        data: {"hline": lineLabel[currentLine]},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
              //do successful stuff
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that was me not going back to the original code - I was trying all kinds of things.  That was not the problem as we had that problem before I made those changes.